# Python 3.12 does not support the package cloud-sql-python-connector on Windows 11

Tags: python

I have upgraded from Python 3.11 to Python 3.12. After I have upgraded I am unable to install the package "cloud-sql-python-connector".

My colleague confirmed that he can install it on Python 3.11, but not 3.12.

**requirements.txt**

```
cloud-sql-python-connector
flask
flask-cors
google-api-python-client
google-cloud-secret-manager
jira
matplotlib
numpy
PyYAML
python-pptx
pg8000
sqlalchemy
python-dateutil
Pillow
requests
```

**Command output:**

```
Collecting cloud-sql-python-connector
  Using cached cloud_sql_python_connector-1.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (24 kB)
Collecting aiohttp (from cloud-sql-python-connector)
  Using cached aiohttp-3.9.1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (7.6 kB)
Collecting cryptography>=38.0.3 (from cloud-sql-python-connector)
  Using cached cryptography-41.0.7-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl.metadata (5.3 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: Requests in c:\users\admin\code\jira-statistics-as-powerpoint\venv\lib\site-packages (from cloud-sql-python-connector) (2.31.0)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth in c:\users\admin\code\jira-statistics-as-powerpoint\venv\lib\site-packages (from cloud-sql-python-connector) (2.24.0)
Collecting cffi>=1.12 (from cryptography>=38.0.3->cloud-sql-python-connector)
  Using cached cffi-1.16.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (1.5 kB)
Collecting attrs>=17.3.0 (from aiohttp->cloud-sql-python-connector)
  Using cached attrs-23.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting multidict<7.0,>=4.5 (from aiohttp->cloud-sql-python-connector)
  Using cached multidict-6.0.4.tar.gz (51 kB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
  Installing backend dependencies: started
  Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
Collecting yarl<2.0,>=1.0 (from aiohttp->cloud-sql-python-connector)
  Using cached yarl-1.9.3-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (29 kB)
Collecting frozenlist>=1.1.1 (from aiohttp->cloud-sql-python-connector)
  Using cached frozenlist-1.4.0.tar.gz (90 kB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
Collecting aiosignal>=1.1.2 (from aiohttp->cloud-sql-python-connector)
  Using cached aiosignal-1.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (7.6 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: cachetools<6.0,>=2.0.0 in c:\users\admin\code\jira-statistics-as-powerpoint\venv\lib\site-packages (from google-auth->cloud-sql-python-connector) (5.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1 in c:\users\admin\code\jira-statistics-as-powerpoint\venv\lib\site-packages (from google-auth->cloud-sql-python-connector) (0.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: rsa<5,>=3.1.4 in c:\users\admin\code\jira-statistics-as-powerpoint\venv\lib\site-packages (from google-auth->cloud-sql-python-connector) (4.9)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in c:\users\admin\code\jira-statistics-as-powerpoint\venv\lib\site-packages (from Requests->cloud-sql-python-connector) (3.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\users\admin\code\jira-statistics-as-powerpoint\venv\lib\site-packages (from Requests->cloud-sql-python-connector) (3.6)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\admin\code\jira-statistics-as-powerpoint\venv\lib\site-packages (from Requests->cloud-sql-python-connector) (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\admin\code\jira-statistics-as-powerpoint\venv\lib\site-packages (from Requests->cloud-sql-python-connector) (2023.11.17)
Collecting pycparser (from cffi>=1.12->cryptography>=38.0.3->cloud-sql-python-connector)
  Using cached pycparser-2.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (118 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1<0.6.0,>=0.4.6 in c:\users\admin\code\jira-statistics-as-powerpoint\venv\lib\site-packages (from pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1->google-auth->cloud-sql-python-connector) (0.5.1)
Using cached cloud_sql_python_connector-1.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
Using cached cryptography-41.0.7-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl (2.7 MB)
Using cached aiohttp-3.9.1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (362 kB)
Using cached cffi-1.16.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (181 kB)
Using cached yarl-1.9.3-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (75 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: frozenlist, multidict
  Building wheel for frozenlist (pyproject.toml): started
  Building wheel for frozenlist (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
  Building wheel for multidict (pyproject.toml): started
  Building wheel for multidict (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
Failed to build frozenlist multidict

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  Building wheel for frozenlist (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [33 lines of output]
  *********************
  * Accelerated build *
  *********************
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\frozenlist
  copying frozenlist\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\frozenlist
  running egg_info
  writing frozenlist.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to frozenlist.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to frozenlist.egg-info\top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'frozenlist.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.lib' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dll' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.a' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.obj' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'frozenlist\*.html'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
  adding license file 'LICENSE'
  writing manifest file 'frozenlist.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  copying frozenlist\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\frozenlist
  copying frozenlist\_frozenlist.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\frozenlist
  copying frozenlist\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\frozenlist
  running build_ext
  building 'frozenlist._frozenlist' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for frozenlist
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  Building wheel for multidict (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [74 lines of output]
  *********************
  * Accelerated build *
  *********************
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
  copying multidict\_abc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
  copying multidict\_compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
  copying multidict\_multidict_base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
  copying multidict\_multidict_py.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
  copying multidict\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
  running egg_info
  writing multidict.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to multidict.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to multidict.egg-info\top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'multidict.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\_multidict.html'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.so'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.pyd'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.pyd'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
  adding license file 'LICENSE'
  writing manifest file 'multidict.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pk6a7buh\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_py.py:207: _Warning: Package 'multidict._multilib' is absent from the `packages` configuration.
  !!
  
          ********************************************************************************
          ############################
          # Package would be ignored #
          ############################
          Python recognizes 'multidict._multilib' as an importable package[^1],
          but it is absent from setuptools' `packages` configuration.
  
          This leads to an ambiguous overall configuration. If you want to distribute this
          package, please make sure that 'multidict._multilib' is explicitly added
          to the `packages` configuration field.
  
          Alternatively, you can also rely on setuptools' discovery methods
          (for example by using `find_namespace_packages(...)`/`find_namespace:`
          instead of `find_packages(...)`/`find:`).
  
          You can read more about "package discovery" on setuptools documentation page:
  
          - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html
  
          If you don't want 'multidict._multilib' to be distributed and are
          already explicitly excluding 'multidict._multilib' via
          `find_namespace_packages(...)/find_namespace` or `find_packages(...)/find`,
          you can try to use `exclude_package_data`, or `include-package-data=False` in
          combination with a more fine grained `package-data` configuration.
  
          You can read more about "package data files" on setuptools documentation page:
  
          - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html
  
  
          [^1]: For Python, any directory (with suitable naming) can be imported,
                even if it does not contain any `.py` files.
                On the other hand, currently there is no concept of package data
                directory, all directories are treated like packages.
          ********************************************************************************
  
  !!
    check.warn(importable)
  copying multidict\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
  copying multidict\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
  running build_ext
  building 'multidict._multidict' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for multidict
ERROR: Could not build wheels for frozenlist, multidict, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Are there any solutions on how to install "cloud-sql-python-connector" with Python 3.12?

Comment: It is the other way, the package does not support Python 3.12, so your obvious solution is to downgrade python to 3.11

Comment: Is there any Specific reason to use Python 3.12, If Not then you can downgrade and install required packages

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector/issues/900

Comment: Thanks matszwecja! I will wait for the release.

Comment: There's really not much we can advise you other than downgrade or waiting for support from package devs. As can be seen from issue, it is WIP.

Comment: Your other option is to try and build things from source. But as the error message mentions, you'll need at least a (recent) Visual C(++) compiler.

Comment: `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/`  Did you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As can be seen on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/cloud-sql-python-connector/), even though the latest release of `cloud-sql-python-connector` (v 1.4.3) was on Nov 15, 2023, the package only has support for `python 3.8, 3.9, 3.10 and 3.11`. Perhaps in the future, there will be support for Python 3.12 but for now, best bet would be to revert back to python 3.11.